# Create a blockchain platform to store students and its degree results on it

Tags: solidity, blockchain, private-blockchain, nodejs

I would like to create a application on blockchain where i will store all students data and their results on blockchain

So anyone having a idea how can i do that or is that feasible to create a that type of system.

I have knowledge of PHP, NODEJS and Basic of Ethereum and Solidit

Comment: You can not say ethereum is `private-blockchain`. please, remove the tag from your question.

Comment: The idea can be implemented with own POA private Ethereum-based blockchain.

Comment: @MaheshRajput  this is because it is possible to create a private-blockchain with ethereum.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Like your comments and question, I would like to refer this: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/hands-on-get-started-with-infura-and-ipfs-on-ethereum-b63635142af0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is feasible to create that type of system using ethereum blockchain.
You can check this tutorial to create a complete dapp http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/the-ultimate-ethereum-dapp-tutorial

Also for development, you can use private blockchain so first read the documentation of solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/installing-solidity.html. 
For backend you can use node.js it has wider support.

Comment: But how can i show the whole data publicly on ethereum as i know ethereum shows only transaction....what if i want to show the whole data publicly ??

Comment: you can use web3.utils.hexToAscii(hex) to show hex data from blockchain

check documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers that need to be answered first.

**Do you want the data to be viewed by any one or permissioned users can view the data?**

As ethereum is public blockchain and data on this can be viewed by anyone. You can spin up your own private node and create your own network but still the users in that network wil be able to view the data. Another way is to encrypt the data offchain and only allow users to view data with specific address or any business logic you can use to give access to user but the problem is that it can become expensive as each byte of data is responsible for the transaction fee

**How much data do you want to store on blockchain?**

The most expensive operation on the blockchain is the state change or storing information. And when each byte of data will result in more gas used. And there is a limit to the gas too as the block limit is 7 million. For that you have to split the data into multiple transactions and this can increase the complexity.

**Other options**

You can use hyper legder which has some mechanism to permission access and is private. For large amount of data you can use IPFS or any other distributed storage technology.

For development nodejs is the best the option as it has good and vast community and you can find many implementations and examples in this technology. You can find many blockchain native libraries that are totally built for nodejs